# Smart commits don't work

Tags: bitbucket, jira, smart-commits

When I try to use Smart commits using the syntax described in Jira documentation it doesn't transition the issue. When I go to the detail I can see the issue is linked to the coresponding commits, but it didn't transition.

I was using the default Kanban workflow and I assumed `Done` would be the correct command in order to transition to the `Done` state (Textual worflow representation seems to call the transition `Done`). Since this didn't happen I tried adding explicit transition from `In Progress` to `Done` named `close`, which didn't work either.

The commit messages were

```
PROJ-1 #Done Closing
PROJ-1 #close Closing
```

I checked the logs to make sure [invalid commit email](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/dvcs-smart-commits-are-not-working-due-to-user-not-found-by-email-779160764.html) was not the issue (to double check) and there's nothing else I believe to be related to my problem. You can see the log's content below

```
2017-02-14 17:31:06,721 Caesium-1-2 INFO ServiceRunner     [c.a.j.p.h.service.ping.RefreshConnectionStatusJobHandler] Running RefreshConnectionStatusJobHandler...
2017-02-14 17:31:07,211 Caesium-1-3 INFO ServiceRunner     [c.a.j.p.h.service.connect.InstallGlancesJobHandler] Running InstallGlancesJobHandler...
2017-02-14 17:31:07,211 Caesium-1-3 INFO ServiceRunner     [c.a.j.p.h.service.connect.InstallGlancesJobHandler] There is no link to HipChat, no need to install glances.
2017-02-14 17:37:16,377 Caesium-1-3 INFO ServiceRunner     [c.a.crowd.directory.DbCachingRemoteDirectory] INCREMENTAL synchronisation for directory [ 10000 ] starting
2017-02-14 17:37:16,377 Caesium-1-3 INFO ServiceRunner     [c.a.crowd.directory.DbCachingRemoteDirectory] Attempting INCREMENTAL synchronisation for directory [ 10000 ]
2017-02-14 17:37:16,518 Caesium-1-3 INFO ServiceRunner     [c.a.crowd.directory.DbCachingRemoteDirectory] INCREMENTAL synchronisation complete for directory [ 10000 ] in [ 141ms ]
2017-02-14 18:31:06,726 Caesium-1-2 INFO ServiceRunner     [c.a.j.p.h.service.ping.RefreshConnectionStatusJobHandler] Running RefreshConnectionStatusJobHandler...
2017-02-14 18:31:07,218 Caesium-1-1 INFO ServiceRunner     [c.a.j.p.h.service.connect.InstallGlancesJobHandler] Running InstallGlancesJobHandler...
2017-02-14 18:31:07,218 Caesium-1-1 INFO ServiceRunner     [c.a.j.p.h.service.connect.InstallGlancesJobHandler] There is no link to HipChat, no need to install glances.
2017-02-14 18:37:16,391 Caesium-1-4 INFO ServiceRunner     [c.a.crowd.directory.DbCachingRemoteDirectory] INCREMENTAL synchronisation for directory [ 10000 ] starting
2017-02-14 18:37:16,391 Caesium-1-4 INFO ServiceRunner     [c.a.crowd.directory.DbCachingRemoteDirectory] Attempting INCREMENTAL synchronisation for directory [ 10000 ]
2017-02-14 18:37:16,516 Caesium-1-4 INFO ServiceRunner     [c.a.crowd.directory.DbCachingRemoteDirectory] INCREMENTAL synchronisation complete for directory [ 10000 ] in [ 125ms ]
```

I also checked the Bitbucket connecton in Development tools section and the Smart commit producer is listed as one of the capabilities

[image: connectivity]

Comment: Silly question, but you have double checked that smart commits have been enabled?

Comment: Yes, I enabled them when I was configuring the application link to our Bitbucker server and when I go back to check I see this http://i.imgur.com/Allkf9b.png

Answer (score 1):

This issue may be related to JIRA permission. Check If the user which you are using for commit has the issue transition permission in JIRA.